# R.string.string_name generates different id compared to the id associated with string_name in R.java file

Tags: java, android

I was getting **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException** error with **context.getString(R.string.event_home)** command. I did have a string named **event_home** in R.java file. So when I compare the key given by R.string.event_home and compared it with key present in R.java file I found out that both were different and that is why I was getting the error stated above. I don't understand why keys were different. I will appreciate any explanation/ help regarding this so that I can fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild your project. If it doesn't work, you can also delete your R.java file and it will generate again.

Comment: Sorry mistyped I was using R.string only. I have corrected it. Sorry :)

Comment: I have tried this but still I am getting android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException due to incorrect string id.

Answer (score 0):

This was basically the issue with evaluator present in emulator which was giving wrong answer in evaluating the statement R.string.string_name. So when I print on console it was giving right value. Silly me I didn't checked on console before!!.